# How create Action strip for more objects in NLA

Tags: animation

how can I do one clip for many animated objects? I can add objects to Keying sets and key together, but clips are created separately for every object, but I want create only one clip. Thanks

**EDIT**
For example: I will create robot with custom rig. Two legs, one body, two hands. I dont want use armature. And if I will make walkcycle I will have many clips for one walkcycle? It has not sense for reusing, because I will have many clips for one walkcycle. I can use Armature, but often it is not character animation. Last project what I done was house which was rotated, open roof and open windows. This action was repeated. So in Softimage I made clip and used it again. Without armatures or any bones. Maybe it is not possible in Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after discussion in another forum: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?321310-Create-clip-for-more-objects It looks that it is not possible :( I can only use armature as workaround and use parenting objects. Bones dont have to be connected, so I can create only one bone for one object, but I can create clip for all bones together.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to animate one object, then copy it to the others. To copy, select all object you want to use the same animation data, the one to copy from as the last selected. Then execute **Object** > **Make Links...** (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>), and choose **Animation Data**.

[image: 1a]

Note that if *Location* property is keyframed in the action, all objects using the action will jump to the same location. To offset from original location, use *Delta Location* instead. The same goes with *Rotation* and *Scale* properties.

**EDIT:** If you want to merge animation data of several objects, I don't think that's possible. At most, you can manipulate all of them in the *Dope Sheet*, where animation data for all animated objects are displayed. I use this a lot when I have to synchronize the animation of several objects (three, in illustration below) at once:

[image: 2a]

Comment: Thanks for tip with Delta Location :) Maybe my question was not clear, because you answered for another thing. I try it differently: I came from Softimage, when I create some complex object, I create rig for animation controled by null (empty node in Blender). I want animate every empty separately, I dont want share animation. But in Softimage, I group all "empty" under "Model" and I can create only one clip for all emptys. And now I want same in Blender. But I have one animation clip for one control empty. Maybe there is another workflow in Blender.

Comment: @user2332312 Yes, "create one clip" is a bit ambiguous :) Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is really bad :( I also used Maya and this is normal workflow. Maybe there is another in Blender. For example: I will create robot with custom rig. Two legs, one body, two hands. I will not use armature. And if I will do walkcycle I will have many clips for one walkcycle? It has not sense for reusing, because I will have many clips for one walkcycle. I have to watch some videotutorials for workflow.

Comment: @user2332312 Any reason why you won't use armature? So far, armature is the only way in Blender to have virtually unlimited objects to control in one animation data. The workflow you've described seems harder than it needs to be, for character animation. CMIIW.

Comment: @user2332312 If you want to clarify your quesion, please edit on original quesion instead of commenting. Btw, I'm afraid you still need a more detailed example to explain your question better. You comments seem too far from the original post.

Comment: Adhi: I added example in above, when Armature is not good. But there is many another example. For example camera rig. I can animate camera, interest node (in Blender you have to create it) and whole camera root node. All this three object will animate together and create animation clip in NLA. Later I can reuse it.